# Displaying an NSArray on a pre-populated table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, nspredicate

So for my app I have a text field and a search button. The user enters a username and I want it to be displayed on the 'usersTable'. This is the code for that:

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"search button pressed");
    NSString *searchedText = _searchField.text;
    //Queries for users.
    PFQuery *filterQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [filterQuery setLimit:1000];
    [filterQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (!error) {
            // Here you can store fetched data of parse to your array.
            NSArray *filteredData;
            filteredData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:objects];

        }
    }];
     NSArray *filteredData;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchedText];
     NSArray *newArray = [filteredData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];



}
```

However, I've got no idea at all if this would work as a filtering system and on how I would populate my 'usersTable' which is a UITableView with the array NSArray. The table is already populated and I want to remove everything that is already their and display the results in the NSArray, newArray. Could anybody please approve this code and tell me how I'd remove, and then populate with the new array?

Thanks for your help

Comment: By the way this uses Parse and their are no arrays, and that is why I'm not sure how I'd clear the rows.

Comment: Set a variable that will change when you are searching/not searching. In your tableview datasource delegate methods, you can point to the search results array when this variable is set.

UISearchController may also be something to look into.

Comment: why not just `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is by using UISearchController, here is an example: http://www.jhof.me/simple-uisearchcontroller-implementation/

A quick way to do it is create a BOOl property that will change when you are searching/not searching. In your tableview datasource delegate methods, you can query the correct array based on this value.

Comment: I don't have a UITableView controller so I can't do this embed step: will it still work? Select the Table View Controller and, from the top menu, choose Editor>Embed In>Navigation Controller

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. It also says to:  Go back to the storyboard and add a new Table View Controller, then repeat the steps of embedding it in a navigation controller. 
    I can't do this becuse this is in a compose message view controller and its a UITableView not a UITableViewController.

Comment: also I can't find editor>embed in>navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate your 'usersTable' which is a UITableView with an NSArray.
Your userTable (let's call it myArray) can be a @property of the class:

```
@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end
```

Then in order to populate your tableView with the data from this array make sure to use the array in the tableView delegate methods. For example
:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.